# Modifying several pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many (around 40) different DataFrames (16 columns x 6000 rows) with the same headers and index that contain True/False type of data.

What I would like to do is add the sum (True = 1, False = 0) of these DataFrames to a single DataFrame. I have tried doing a for loop that uses applymap but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
    while lookback < 210:
        signal_count = locals()["mavg_"+str(lookback)+"_signal"].applymap(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
        lookback += 5
```

The dataframes are named mavg_lookback_signal where lookback is from 10 to 200 with steps of 5.

Comment: You can just call `sum` on the dataframe, `True` will be evaluated as `1` and `False` as `0`, this will be much quicker than calling `applymap`

Comment: `locals()["mavg_"+str(lookback)+"_signal"]` is a sign something's gone wrong with your abstraction.  (Keep data out of your variable names, as the man said.)  Why not use a dictionary instead, with lookback as the key and your frames as the values?

Comment: Thank you! Apparently this is a recurring issue with beginners. :)